# Completion for gradle not applying

Tags: fish

I'm trying to understand why the gradle completion isn't applying.

Since `gw` seems to be a keyword for the completion, I created an alias:

```
alias gw='./gradlew'
```

(My project uses gradle wrapper.  I don't have gradle installed globally.)

When I type `gw <tab>` it just does the standard file system completion.  I'm expecting something more like when typing `git <tab>`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of an alias, use a function, and declare that it **wraps** gradle

```
function gw --wraps gradlew
    ./gradlew $argv
end
```

See https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/function.html